# Is there any alternative api to NPPasswordChangeNotify in windows10 to support SSO

Tags: security, window, single-sign-on, win32-process

We have a windows native application developed on C++ win32 technology, which supports SSO feature since the beginning of Windows XP by [Implementing a Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/implementing-a-credential-manager). Since the beginning of Windows 7, SSO functionality is breaking when user changes the password because [NPPasswordChangeNotify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/npapi/nf-npapi-nppasswordchangenotify#remarks) api is not supported beginning with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.

Is there any alternative api to NPPasswordChangeNotify to get notification when user changes the password.

Thanks,

Vishu